# How to get post content from its ID in WordPress multi site?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, wordpress

I'm running a multi site and I want to pull post with certain categories from two blogs. Therefore I am running a loop for each of the blog to pull the posts as one of the category is in blog 1 while the other category is in blog 2.

```
    <?php $value = array(); ?>
    <?php 
            // Get the values from $_POST
            $original_blog_id = get_current_blog_id(); // get current blog

            $bids = array(1,2); // all the blog_id's to loop through  EDIT

            foreach($bids as $bid):
            switch_to_blog($bid); 


              $args = array(
                'tax_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'Music',
                        'field' => 'slug',
                        'terms' => array('artist', 'club')
                    ),
                        )
                    );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );



    ?>

    <?php $postids = array(); ?>

    <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { ?>

        <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

            <?php $postids[]=get_the_ID(); ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

         <?php $value[] = $postids; ?>
    <?php
        } else {
            // no posts found
            echo 'Nothing found.';
        }  

    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<?php 

    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($value));
    $list = iterator_to_array($it,false);

    $posts = new WP_Query(array( 
        'post__in' => $list,  
        'post_type' => 'post',
        ));



?>

<?php 
    foreach ($posts as $post) {
    setup_postdata($post);  
?>

<?php echo the_title(); ?>
<?php
}


 wp_reset_postdata();     ?>

<?php switch_to_blog($original_blog_id);  ?>
```

The reason why I'm getting the `IDs` inside an array:

```
<?php $postids[]=get_the_ID(); ?>
```

because I want to fetch random post's. If at this point instead of the above statement I get the title and content of the posts then it will show in sequential order. Something like this:

```
BLOG1: POST1,POST2, POST : BLOG2: POST1, POST2, POST3
```

But I want Posts in random order like this:

```
BLOG1: POST1, BLOG2: POST3, BLOG1: POST2, BLOG2: POST1: BLOG2: POST2
```

So everything is working fine, I am able to get the `posts IDs` even outside the foreach loop but the  problem is:

I am not able to get post content from those `IDs`. It only gives me posts from blog 2 because the current blog is 2. But it doesn't show anything from blog1 even though the `postID` is in the `list` array.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be the following, just add the code into your themes `footer.php` files, although this can be put anywhere within your WordPress theme, example:

```
<?php

  if (!function_exists('display_posts_from_blogs')) {
    function display_posts_from_blogs($blog_id) {
    global $switched;
    switch_to_blog($blog_id); //switched to blog id 2, for example

    // Get latest Post
    $latest_posts = get_posts('category=-3&numberposts=6&orderby=post_name&order=DSC');
    $cnt =0;
?> 


 <ul>
    <?php foreach($latest_posts as $post) : setup_postdata($post);?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post->ID); ?>" title="<?php echo $post->post_title; ?>"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
        </li>                                
    <?php endforeach ; ?>

<?php restore_current_blog(); //switched back to main site 
} //end function
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain your code, How'd I get posts from `blog1` If I use only `switch_to_blog(2)`?

Comment: Usage of `switch_to_blog(2)` is only the example, use your actual blog ID. So you can wrap the above code in a function, pass a parameter `blog_id` , for example, to this function and then invoke the function according your needs, see the edit of the answer.